# metric topology category properties

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d$) be a metric space without isolated points and $A$ be a subset of X such that each point of $A$ is an isolated point of it. Show that $A$ is nowhere dense in $X.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it's not the case that $A$ is nowhere dense, that is, $\overline{A}$ contains an open region (i.e. an open region in which $A$ is dense). Choose a point $x \in A$ from this region (note that we must be able to do this).

Since $x$ is isolated in $A$, there must be some $r > 0$ such that $B(x; r) \cap A = \lbrace x \rbrace$, but also $B(x; r) \subseteq \overline{A}$. However, $x$ is not isolated in $X$, so there must be some $y \in B(x; r) \setminus \lbrace x \rbrace$. Note that, by the triangle inequality,

$$B(y; \min \lbrace r - d(x, y), d(x, y) \rbrace) \subseteq B(x; r) \setminus \lbrace x \rbrace.$$

However, this implies that,

$$B(y; \min \lbrace r - d(x, y), d(x, y) \rbrace) \cap A \subseteq (B(x; r) \setminus \lbrace x \rbrace) \cap A = \emptyset,$$

which means we've found an open set in $B(x; r) \subseteq \overline{A}$, but which does not intersect $A$. This is a contradiction. Therefore, $A$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: Please calrify the last implication...